# Unable to sent mail by using gmail smtp server

Tags: php, smtp, cakephp-3.0, pyopenssl

Hi i am unable to use gmail smtp service to send email from my website which is develop by using cakephp3.x of the php framework. Blow is the error i am getting

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)
```

Here is my code

```
Email::configTransport('gmail', [
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => '30',
            'username' => 'pradeepta20@gmail.com',
            'password' => '******',
            'className' => 'Smtp' // <------ there it is
        ]);
        $email_obj = new Email();
        $email_obj->template('default')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->to("pradeepta20@gmail.com")
                ->from(["someone@gmail.com" => "Test"])
                ->subject("Testing STMP EMAIL")
                ->transport('gmail');

        if ($email_obj->send("Some Text Message"))
            echo "Email Sent!!";
        else
            echo "Error!!";
        exit;
```

Comment: go through this link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Help Site](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) there is a sentence `If your device or application supports SSL - connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465.`, so try to delete `ssl://` prefix from your host.